# Where clause problems

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a list of custom objects

```
List<Quest> m_quests = new List<Quest>();
```

in another class I try to query it

```
var CurentQuests = from a in gLogic.m_quests
                                   where a.m_hero == m_heronbr
                                   && a.m_complete != 100f
                                   select a;
```

But the `WHERE` and `&&` Clause do not seem to get checked and the query returns the complete list. I have tried different variations with where `a.m_hero.equals(m_heronbr)` and the `like`. Is this a problem with the custom object?

---

Extra info.
the list of "quests" contains items from custom class Quest
it only stores variables like the ones in question witch are m_hero == int
and m_complete == Float

Comment: 1) What are you trying to achieve with your where clause? 2) What are the data types for the fields used in this clause?

Comment: What is `m_hero`? If that's a reference type, does it overload the `==` operator? Otherwise just the references are compared. Edit: However, that wouldn't cause all to be returned but none.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You should try to include a very simple, reproducible example. In the one you've specified, we don't see any `Quest` objects being added to the list, nor do we see what properties are set.

Comment: Where are you seeing the bad results?  Remember that a query is just a wrapper around the original collection until you call `ToList` or `ToArray`, so if you're looking in the debugger you'll still "see" the entire collection behind-the-scenes.

Comment: @chiapa it's the syntax to represent a literal `float` (`System.Single`)

Comment: @chiapa See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#sectionToggle0

Comment: Are you sure you have entries in that list with `t` _exactly_ equal to 100f? That is, 100.000000000000000? Not 100.0000000000001? You should not compare floating-point numbers for equality.

Comment: We need an MCVE or everyone will just be guessing.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: AWWW god damnd. to late in the day. and to long since I last dabled in LINQ
@DStanley is correct forgot to "toList" it.

Comment: Instead, use something like `if (Math.Abs(x - 1.0) < 1.0e-12)`.

Comment: @JazeMan: if you want to replace the original list you just need: `m_quests = CurentQuests.ToList()`. But you can also execute a LINQ query in the debugger to inspect the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will argue that there is nothing wrong with your where clause, and can prove it here:

```
public class Quest
{
    public int m_hero { get; set; }
    public double m_complete { get; set; }
}

private static void Main()
{
    const int m_heronbr = 10;

    List<Quest> m_quests = new List<Quest>
    {
        new Quest {m_complete = 50, m_hero = m_heronbr},
        new Quest {m_complete = 75, m_hero = m_heronbr},
        new Quest {m_complete = 100, m_hero = m_heronbr}
    };

    var curentQuests =
        from a in m_quests
        where a.m_hero == m_heronbr
              && a.m_complete != 100
        select a;

    Console.WriteLine(curentQuests.Count());
}
```

Output:

> 2

Most likely, as John Saunders pointed out, the problem has to do with your floating-point comparison. If you're doing any math with `m_hero`, it is quite likely that you are running into rounding errors.

Try something like this instead:

```
var curentQuests = from a in m_quests
                   where a.m_hero == m_heronbr
                   && Convert.ToInt32(a.m_complete) != 100
                   select a;
```

Comment: This is not actualy the ansver to the problem, the problem was solved by   D Stanley.

But it solves a problem I would haw met today while going further with the code.